# Retrieve customCell label text value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with custom Cell and text in a label for each cell

When i'm selecting a cell i'm highlighting this cell with another color and saving it in a variable so that when i'm using my "next" button, i'm going to another view with the last selected cell value

My problem is that the variable is retrieving the name of the label and not the text i assigned to it ..

[image]

Comment: Hi. Looks strange to me. Can you try to implement func tableView(UITableView, didDeselectRowAt: IndexPath) instead of didSelectRowAt? Jut a guess.

Comment: How are you retrieving the last selected cell? It might be reusing the cell.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do it like this in your func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath).

```
selectedCellText = careerSource[indexPath.row]
```